# Performance of Extract-Transform operations

Tags: performance-tuning, import, data

I'm doing simple data analysis, where I load some "date-time" data from a file. The data is a simple list, but there are 41,000 values in total. Here's a short sample:

```
"26.11.2014 13:56:17" "26.11.2014 13:56:18" "26.11.2014 13:56:20"
```

Here is my code, which extracts a list of date-times from a file and transform the results into list of seconds (integers):

```
l = Import["c:\\tmp\\1.csv", "List"];   
l2 = AbsoluteTime /@ l;
```

The problem is that it takes about 15 seconds and 100% of a CPU core to do the step 2 (AbsoluteTime) for a mere 41k elements.

Are there ways to speed up this operation?

Maybe Import into a list of Dates, not into a generic list? Or should I change the strategy altogether and prepare data before loading into the Mathematica?

Answer (score 2):

```
l = ConstantArray[{"26.11.2014 13:56:17", "26.11.2014 13:56:18" , 
                   "26.11.2014 13:56:20"}, {10000}] // Flatten;
```

I can get 20x speed up by converting it to `DateList` form:

```
AbsoluteTime[
  ToExpression@StringSplit[#, " " | "." | ":"][[{3, 2, 1, 4, 5, 6}]] 
  ]& /@  l; // Timing
```

> ```
> {1.684811, Null}
> ```

Comment: 0 down vote accept
 

I got 15x with this feat. Thanks.

Comment: @IlyaSorokin what do you mean by 0 down vote accept? :) p.s. please take a [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour)